# Can a function process multiple custom objects without using a pipeline?

Tags: powershell

I'll use `Test-Path` as the example here.

You can pass the array as parameters to the function:

`Test-Path 'C:\', 'G:\`

Or they can be piped:

`'C:\', 'G:\ | Test-Path`

Now this is simple enough as it's just an array of strings.

But what if I wanted to do that with objects?

Again, I'm skimping on the details here. But I have a function that has 3 arguments:

1. String (required)
2. String (optional)
3. Switch (optional)

If I'm calling the function with only one object. All of these invocations are valid.

```
My-Function -RequiredString 'requiredstring' -OptionalString 'optionalstring' -MySwitch
My-Function -RequiredString 'requiredstring'
My-Function -RequiredString 'requiredstring' -MySwitch
```

If I want to process multiple objects at once. I do something like this:

```
$objs = @(
    (New-Object PSObject -Property @{ RequiredString='requiredstring'; OptionalString='optionalstring'; MySwitch=$true} ),
    (New-Object PSObject -Property @{ RequiredString='requiredstring'} ),
    (New-Object PSObject -Property @{ RequiredString='requiredstring'; MySwitch=$true} )
)

$objs | My-Function
```

Is there any way that I can call the function to process multiple objects without using a pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

If you want to pass an array of objects to the function, the function will need to be re-written to expect and iterate through the array.

The pipeline is doing that for you, by "unrolling" the array and passing one object at a time to the function.  If you want to pass the array as a parameter, then that unrolling/iteration will need to be done inside the function.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but that's fine. Piping the objects is fine. I was just hoping they could be passed as an array so I could do some 'reporting' on them in `end` block. but oh well.

Comment: You can still make the function work with an array.  You just can't do anything in the call syntax that will make it work with an array passed as a parameter if it was written to work with a scalar (single object).

Comment: It's fine. Using piped input isn't a problem.